# Can't connect to a running server in vagrant with windows OS

Tags: localhost, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I recently installed vagrant in windows 10 and everything just work fine but as I know almost nothing about Virtualization or VM's I got a problem when connecting to a server.

I have a nodejs server running in a vagrant box and of course a address or "local host" but can't connect to it through my main OS, just the typical "Problem Loading Page" or <kbd>can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:8000.</kbd>

I'm using ssh instead of winssh, idk if it's useful.

I assume is a problem with the localhost, which of course are different between vagrant and windows.

The docs didn't where helpful.

Comment: Just configure the network adapter of your VM and use a proper IP address. Ask for more advice at https://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Because it seems like you may be new to Vagrant the quickest and easiest way for you to access your VM via localhost is to set up [port forwarding](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/networking/forwarded_ports#) in your Vagrantfile.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
end
```

Using the example above you’ve forwarded your host port, 8080, to your vm’s port 80. So when you go to localhost:8080 it will return whatever is listening on port 80 of your VM. Just make sure that if you have a firewall setup in your VM you open port 80.